# Why does the Cucumber test app fail to access Sinatra's settings in 1.4.x but not 1.3.x?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cucumber

I was trying to upgrade from Sinatra 1.3.x to 1.4.2. The specs run fine, but Cucumber fails with:

```
undefined local variable or method `settings' for #<RechargeWorld:0x007ffbd606ba60> (NameError)
```

The relevant portion of the `env.rb` looks like this:

```
  class RechargeWorld
    include Capybara::DSL
    include RSpec::Expectations
    include RSpec::Matchers

    def db
      @db ||= CouchRest.database(settings.db)
    end
  end
```

Some of this code (note: I added the `db` method) was generated by [cucumber-sintra](https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber-sinatra), and it worked fine with 1.3.x but fails with any version 1.4.x. The latest version of cucumber-sinatra generates basically an identical `env.rb`.

The app is [available on Github](https://github.com/awendt/recharge).

Was anything changed with the settings hash between 1.3.x and 1.4 that could be causing this? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Github seems to be down so I can't try this myself, but have you tried calling the `app` variable that Capybara uses, `Capybara.app.db`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. That results `undefined method 'settings' for #<Rack::URLMap:0x007fed6a4fb370> (NoMethodError)` :( But I will post an answer that works, feel free to comment on that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the [official Cucumber+Sinatra guide](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/sinatra) and noticed the `app` method returning `Sinatra::Application`.

So I changed the `env.rb` portion to this:

```rb
class RechargeWorld
  include Capybara::DSL
  include RSpec::Expectations
  include RSpec::Matchers

  def db
    @db ||= CouchRest.database(Sinatra::Application.settings.db)
  end
end
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: It does! But I figured since I need this only for accessing the settings, I could inline it here.